# grub rescue, blind mode

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grubrescue, grub-efi

i updated osx last night and when i try to boot to linux, i get sent to the grub rescue prompt.

i have performed the following steps:

```
set prefix=(hd1,gpt5)/boot/grub  (contains grub.cfg but mod 
                                  files in subdir x86_64-efi)
set root=(hd1,gpt5)
insmod linux
linux /vmlinuz root=/dev/sdb5 ro  # Example: root=/dev/sda1 , /dev/sdb5
initrd /initrd.img
boot
```

the result is:

```
error: no suitable video mode found.
Booting in blind mode
```

and then it stays there forever.  the system does not reboot or restart.

is this because it cannot find my mod files?

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to install my [rEFInd boot manager,](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) along with an EFI filesystem driver (provided with rEFInd) for whatever filesystem holds your Linux kernel (probably ext4fs). You'll need to install the driver manually in OS X, but it's not difficult -- it's just one file that needs to be copied. Once this is set up, rEFInd should detect your Linux kernel(s) and enable you to boot them directly, bypassing GRUB.